# Can we submit an app to appstore, which have an iOS custom framework in Debug mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I had created an iOS framework with Debug mode and added that one into another project which i was exported in Distribution mode. will it create any problem while submitting the app to app store?

Can I submit an application (Distribution mode) to appstore,  which have an iOS custom framework in Debug mode?

Comment: Why would you do that? FYI, my OS X app with a weakly linked F-Script framework has been successfully approved for a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you probably shouldn't.

Debug builds have lots of extra stuff in them to allow the debugger to do it's thing. This extra stuff makes the binary bigger and slower.